# ToastContainer' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Here is my Code:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import loaderIcon from "../../assets/images/loader.gif";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { IOtpProps } from "./otp.types";

export function Otp({ showOtpForm, email, setIsLoggedIn }: IOtpProps) {
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  const [successMsg, setSuccessMsg] = useState("");
  const [otpExpired, setOtpExpired] = useState(false);
  const [incorrectAttempts, setIncorrectAttempts] = useState(0);
  const [disableResend, setDisableResend] = useState(true);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(30);
  const [buttonOpacity, setButtonOpacity] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const serverUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api";

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showOtpForm) {
      // Display toast message for 5 seconds
      toast.success("Otp has been send to your Email", {
        autoClose: 5000,
        style: {
          fontFamily: "Noto Sans",
          fontSize: "15px",
          fontWeight: "600",
          borderRadius: "14px",
        },
      });
    }
  }, [showOtpForm]);

  const handleOtpChange = (e: any) => {
    setOtp(e.target.value);
  };

  const startTimer = () => {
    let count = 30;
    setDisableResend(true);
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      count -= 1;
      setTimer(count);

      if (count === 0) {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        setDisableResend(false);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleResendOtp = async (e: any) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      setSuccessMsg("otp resent successfully");
      setDisableResend(true);
      startTimer();

      const res = await axios.post(
        `${serverUrl}/resend-otp`,
        {
          email,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      if (res.data.error === false) {
        setSuccessMsg("OTP resent successfully");
        setDisableResend(true);
        setTimer(30);
        startTimer();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await axios.post(
      `${serverUrl}/verify-otp`,
      {
        email,
        otp,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(res.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="otp-container">
      {showOtpForm && (
        <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <ToastContainer />
          <div className="otp-container">
            <h2>Enter OTP</h2>
            <p>We have sent a 6-digit OTP in your email.</p>
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="otp-input"
                maxLength={6}
                onChange={handleOtpChange}
              />
            </div>
            {(showOtpForm || otpExpired || incorrectAttempts >= 3) && (
              <div className="resend-otp-btn">
                <span
                  onClick={handleResendOtp}
                  onKeyDown={(e) => e.keyCode === 13}
                  tabIndex={0}
                  role="button"
                  style={{
                    opacity: buttonOpacity,
                    pointerEvents: disableResend ? "none" : "auto",
                  }}
                  //@ts-ignore
                  disabled={disableResend}
                >
                  Resend OTP
                  {disableResend ? `(${timer}s)` : ""}
                </span>
              </div>
            )}

            <button className="submit-btn" onClick={handleLogin} type="button">
              Submit
            </button>
            {loginError && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{loginError}</div>}
            {successMsg && <div style={{ color: "green" }}>{successMsg}</div>}
            {errorMessage && <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errorMessage}</div>}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error: ToastContainer' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
Types of property 'key' are incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

According to official [documentation](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/installation):

> Remember to render the ToastContainer once in your application tree. If you can't figure out where to put it, rendering it in the application root would be the best bet.

Move the `ToastContainer` component to a higher level in your code, such as your root component or parent component that wraps your Otp component:

Here, I am moving it to App.jsx file (Root level)

**App.jsx**

```
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ToastContainer />
      {/* Other components */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After this step, Remove `ToastContainer` from the Otp component.

Let me know, if you have any other questions.